# Can I model page elements using PageObjects in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am using PageObjects (actually LoadableComponent approach) in a Selenium WebDriver testing project. On one of the pages, there's a list of rather complex HTML objects contained in a div. I was thinking, is it possible to model these components as objects?

This is how the page looks like:

```
<div id='container'>
 <div id='component1' class='component'>
 ......
 </div>
 <div id='component1' class='component'>
 ......
 </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to model `div.component` as separate class and return a list of objects from the main model class? Of course, in the `div.component` model class, I would put a bunch of methods related to the component code. 
This would be a "PageElements" pattern..

Comment: Why not? Have you encountered unexpected problems during implementation?

Comment: Olyv, I was asking an opinion on how to implement this...

Comment: IMHO, there should be classes which represent your complex HTML objects. Then you write methods which interacts with elements. The question itself is quite broad without seeing the whole picture of your project structure (I mean what you have already implemented). Page Object pattern is not rigid rule but just a good manner. Implementation is up to you. http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects#Summary

Comment: I already use PageObjects pattern for the whole page, but I wanted to extract the div.component from the code above as separate object. But how do you do that? How do I extract the div and return it as custom object, not as WebElement?

Comment: I do not think you should consider your divs as elements (or objects). They are just a pieces of application which provide you with ability to perform some action. For example, if your div represents header of every web page, why not to put header to a separate class and all the other pages will extend your header. Something like 'public class LoginPage extends CommonHeader'. It would be also interesting to look at your project/project structure.

Comment: The problem is that this divs are really complicated elements and the page model gets a bit to big if I do not do this separation. What I am doing now, I added a class which keeps a reference to a WebElement which is the div inner HTML code and I added in this class the methods I need. Looks fine I guess..

Comment: Why not? You put peace of functionality provided with your 'complicated elements' in separate class, define methods which are provided with those elements and use defined methods (for example `typeInMyComplicatedElement(String textToType)`). As a result you reuse your code and do not have repetitive pieces of code in every class. Hopefully it makes sense for you. If you want you can share a project structure with us to get more attention.